# Conditionally deciding which option is selected in blade

Tags: html, laravel-blade

Im displaying a form as a representation of data in my database. Im using a form because the data is editable by certain users.

The form contains a dropdown list:

```
<select name="Status" id="Status">
        <option id="confirmed" value="Confirmed">Confirmed</option>
        <option id="completed" value="Completed">Completed</option>
        <option id="released" value="Released">Released</option>
        <option id="deleted" value="Deleted">Deleted</option>
</select>
```

When loading the view I pass in a variable '$status' which is from the database. How do I set the 'selected' attribute for which ever option $status is equal to?

Im using blade tempting engine

Answer (score 1):

if you're using blade template you may want to use the Form helper to build your form fields, pass an array of items to be listed as dropdown options on the 2nd parameter and at the 3rd parameter pass your selected value, see the code below for reference

**From controller:**

```
   $selectedValue = "confirmed";
   $statuses = array(
            array("id"=> "confirmed", "value" => "Confirmed"),
            array("id"=> "completed", "value" => "Completed"),
            array("id"=> "released", "value" => "Released"),
            array("id"=> "deleted", "value" => "Deleted"),
   );
    return view("yourview")->with("statuses", $statuses)->with("selectedValue", $selectedValue);
```

On your **view** you could do something like below:

```
{!! Form::select('status', $statuses , $selectedValue, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'status']) !!}
```

Note: the code is untested but should work in your case.

Also please check https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html